# Dynamic form field addition and rendering using spring mvc and javascript

Tags: jquery, spring, forms, spring-mvc

I am having the following use case.

We are designing a web-app in which admin has two features

- Adds/removes the new form fields which will be rendered by other users.
- view the data returned from Database.

Other users can only fill the form (this form contains only the fields added/removed by admin).

We thought of storing the form field attributes in database when admin modify them and render it at run time when non-admin users log in,using jQuery.
But the problem is we are using datatables jQuery plugin to show the contents entered by user to admin. The datatable must be too dynamic such that each time we have to modify its definition according to the fields returned from database.

Is there any other way we can achieve it?

Thanks!